# While Using RoundRobin Partitioning in AzureService bus Transport how to handle sending messages to error queues by both the namespaces

Tags: azureservicebus

I'm using round robin transport partitioning in azure service bus transport ,so how to handle retry,error messages coming back to namespace 
example: message listened from namespace  1 and its error message may be send to namespace 2

Comment: Does that help with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [similar question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/17lovvD3b5o) was asked on the Google group. With two namespaces, you need to consolidate your error queues or monitor both namespaces for the error queue. Depending on what you do, the actual execution of that might be different.

If you use [ServiceControl](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/) you could apply the approach suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/17lovvD3b5o) (an adapter to have all of your messages going into a single namespace which would be used by SC).

If you're not using SC, you'd need to have to implement that forwarding yourself. Unfortunately, there's no way to set up auto forwarding to a different namespace on the entities level. Perhaps a feature to ask from Azure Service Bus team. You could raise a question in the [new client info](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues) to get the conversation going.

Comment: Hi Sean can you Help me on this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413407/set-messaging-unit-of-premium-service-bus-to-4-using-powershellv5

Comment: Not much I can help with tbh. Raised an issue to track for that.