# Set Messaging Unit of premium Service Bus to 4 using PowerShell v5

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, powershell-5.0

I want to set the messaging unit of premium service bus to 4 via PowerShell 5.
Using following command:

```
New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup Default-ServiceBus-NorthEurope `
    -Location NorthEurope -NamespaceName #{PremiumServiceBus} -SkuName "Premium" `
    -Capacity 4
```

It gives capacity is unrecognized variable.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Capacity` parameter is not defined by the Powershlell cmdlet (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicebus/new-azurermservicebusnamespace?view=azurermps-3.8.0)). This is possible using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces#Namespaces_CreateOrUpdate). Looks like a disconnect between the PS library and REST API that MSFT would need to address.

I've [raised an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3780) so that MSFT team can address it.